FIrebase auth in react native expo app with Microsoft provider
We try to set auth using our Microsoft organization provider (it's Azure instance with Firebase authentication. There is a problem with authorization, we can get token from webview auth process.
There are a few checkopoints in handleLogin function, we after fourth checkpoint we have provider and credentials, but then when we put credentials in signInWithCredential function, we get an error Invalid credentials.
Important note: we don't want to have authentication using login and password, auth should be completed only through a work email only.
Did anyone build Firebase authentication using Microsoft provider? Is it possible at all?
here is our AuthProvider:
import "react-native-gesture-handler";
import { createContext, useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Alert } from "react-native";
import {
  exchangeCodeAsync,
  makeRedirectUri,
  useAuthRequest,
  useAutoDiscovery,
} from "expo-auth-session";
import * as WebBrowser from "expo-web-browser";
import { auth } from "@/firebase/config";
import {
  OAuthProvider,
  onAuthStateChanged,
  signInWithCredential,
  signOut,
  User,
} from "firebase/auth";
import { UserAccountDataType } from "@/types/users";
import DataResolver from "@/Providers/DataResolver";

WebBrowser.maybeCompleteAuthSession();

type AuthProps = {
  token: string | null;
  // user: User | null;
  // temp change for mock auth with Alex's account data
  user: UserAccountDataType | null;
  forceLogin: boolean;
  onForceLogin: () => any;
  onLogin: () => Promise<any>;
  onLogout: () => Promise<void>;
  initialized: boolean;
};

const provider = new OAuthProvider("microsoft.com");
provider.setCustomParameters({
  prompt: "consent",
  // client_id: ...,
  tenant: ...,
  // redirectUri: "msauth.<app name>://auth",
});

const AuthContext = createContext<Partial<AuthProps>>({});

export function useAuth() {
  return useContext(AuthContext);
}

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }: any) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState<UserAccountDataType | null>(null);
  const [forceLogin, setForceLogin] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [initialized, setInitialized] = useState(false);

  const discovery = useAutoDiscovery(
    "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<here is tenant>/v2.0"
  );
  const redirectUri = makeRedirectUri({
    scheme: undefined,
    path: "auth",
  });

  console.log({ redirectUri });

  const clientId = '....';
  const [token, setToken] = useState<string | null>(null);

  // Request
  const [request, , promptAsync] = useAuthRequest(
    {
      clientId,
      scopes: ["openid", "profile", "email", "offline_access"],
      redirectUri,
    },
    discovery
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    onAuthStateChanged(auth, async (u) => {
      console.log({ u });

      if (u) {
        console.log("U", u);
        setUser(u);
      } else {
        setUser(u);
  }, []);
  

  // https://docs.expo.dev/guides/authentication/#azure
  const handleLogin = async () => {
    promptAsync().then((codeResponse) => {
      console.log("✅ 1. code response");
      console.log({ codeResponse });
      if (request && codeResponse?.type === "success" && discovery) {
        console.log("✅ 2. code success");
        console.log({ request, codeResponse, discovery });
        exchangeCodeAsync(
          {
            clientId,
            code: codeResponse.params.code,
            extraParams: request.codeVerifier
              ? { code_verifier: request.codeVerifier }
              : undefined,
            redirectUri,
          },
          discovery
        )
          .then(async (res) => {
            console.log("✅ 3. exchange code");
            console.log({ res });
            const { idToken, accessToken } = res;
            setToken(accessToken);
            // console.log({ res });
            const credential = provider.credential({
              idToken,
              accessToken,
            });
            console.log("✅ 4. credential");
            console.log({ credential, provider });

            signInWithCredential(auth, credential)
              .then((userCredential) => {
                console.log("✅ 5. sign in with credential");
                console.log({ userCredential });
                setUser(userCredential.user);
              })
              .catch((error) => {
                Alert.alert("Firebase sign-in error");
                console.error("Firebase sign-in error", error);
              });
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            Alert.alert("Token exchange error");
            console.error("Token exchange error", error);
            // console.error(error);
          });
      }
    });
  };

  const handleLogout = async () => {
    console.log("logout", forceLogin);
    if (forceLogin) {
      setForceLogin(false);
    } else {
      signOut(auth);
    }
  };

  const value = {
    initialized,
    onLogin: handleLogin,
    onLogout: handleLogout,
    onForceLogin: () => setForceLogin(true),
    user,
    forceLogin,
    token,
  };
  return (
    <DataResolver data={value.user} loading={!value.user} error={null}>
      <AuthContext.Provider value={value}>{children}</AuthContext.Provider>
    </DataResolver>
  );
};
```

Error I get: 

 ERROR  Firebase sign-in error [FirebaseError:
Firebase: Invalid IdP response/credential:
http://localhost?&id_token=[id token here]&access_token=[token here]&providerId=microsoft.com (auth/invalid-credential-or-provider-id).]


Could you please share the complete error message screenshot and edit the question?
